# How to open dynamic links in new tab with web py framework?

Tags: python, web.py

I tried `web.seeother("link")`, but this does not open it in a new tab. Now I can generate a link with a `_blank` tag, but then the user has to click on the link separately that is separate button for generating the link and another button to follow that link. I want to perform both with a single click. A server side method to do this would be best.

I am using the web.py framework.

Comment: Isn't it up to the user to decide whether they want a new tab or not?

Comment: the app is such that if the new link doesn't open in a new tab it wouldnt make sense at all.the user is supposed to generate a link,view it in a new tab,comes back to my app generate a link and the cycle goes on an on.

Answer (score 0):

As the document says `web.seeother()` is used for redirecting a user to another page. So a more clear way for asking your question is: "how to make `web.seeother()` open a link in a new tab"?
As I have observed the documents, There is no way to do that on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Not a web.py issue. Cannot be done from server-side by any python or non-python framework, must be done in the Client.

From the client, you can set `target="_blank"` in the HTML, or use javascript with something like `window.open(url)`. Javascript will allow you to set size and position of second window.

Comment: how to do it in the client?

Comment: add `target="_blank"` to your <a> tag. like  `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`